# Evaluate limit of integral in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, limit, numerical-integration

I have the following integral

[image]

I wonder how to show that

[image]

Below I paste my current attempt in Mathematica.

```
tmp1 = Sqrt[Sum[(1/i), {i, 1, d}]]
Limit[Integrate[1/Sqrt[(2*\[Pi])] * Exp[-1/2 * z^2], {z, tmp1, Infinity}], d -> Infinity]
```

Thanks in advance for any pointer or tip.

Comment: I  think you want to integrate over `z` (not `d`) and the syntax is `Limit` (not `Lim`)

Comment: sqrt(sum 1/i) goes to infinity, and the normal cdf goes to zero at infinity. Why do you need Mathematica for this ?

Comment: Know that; want to verify in Mathematica.

Comment: Alexandre, knowing that isn't enough to prove convergence. Since you can't directly (legally) integrate from infinity to infinity.

Comment: @LeeJacobs: [f : x -> int_x^{inf} e^{-z^2/2} / sqrt(2pi) dz is decreasing from 1 to 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function). Therefore, f(u_n) goes to zero iff u_n goes to infinity. What remains to show is that [sum 1/i diverges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))

Comment: Yes, as you can see below, I understand this. The issue is that, you can't just state integral(func, infinity, infinity). This isn't mathematically sound nor computationally. Below is the non-rigorous proof that does follow convention and is mathematically sound. Also, it's a well know fact that sum 1/i diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show this by hand. Given we know that the inner function integrates to 1/2 from 0 to infinity we can then say

1/2 = integral from 0 to sqrt(sum( 1/i )) + integral from sqrt(sum(1/i)) to infinity.

Then

1/2 - integral from 0 to sqrt(sum(1/i)) = integral from sqrt(sum(1/i)) to infinity

and since lim d -> infinity of sqrt(sum(1/i)) = infinity we know that the left hand side is zero and this the integral converges to zero.